# Sourcetree problems after update to version 2.6.3.0

Tags: bitbucket.org, sourcetree

After update sourcetree to version 2.6.3.0 it's showing a login popup repetitive.

[image]

Y put my user/pass and was successful, but after some minutes it show me again the popup.

[image]

Comment: A problem of major updates of sourcetree. For workarounds see [post1](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-keeps-asking-to-authenticate-again-over-and-over/qaq-p/208965), also [post2](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-bitbucket-password-on-windows/qaq-p/241278) and [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489022/sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-github-password). For the Mac see [post4](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-login-and-password/qaq-p/146765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem may happen after a major update of sourcetree.

Some workarounds that helped :

- Verify that you don't have multiple Bitbucket accounts and remove the
  excessive ones.
- Remove any default user names from the authentication tab, and always use urls in `myusername@www.xxx.xxx` format.
- [Wipe SourceTree Preferences](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html)
  and restore your bookmarks.
- Change the password of your account.
- Remove the map at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree`.
- In SourceTree, navigate to *Tools > Options > Git*
  and switch to the system git version (if that is the latest).
- Remove `httpusepath = true` from `git config --global --edit`.
- If using two-factor authentication with GitHub you will need to
  [Create a personal access token and use it with SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/two-factor-authentication-2fa-with-github-in-sourcetree-402033499.html).

These suggestions were collected from the following sources which contain
more suggestions and details :

- [SourceTree keeps asking to authenticate again over and over](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-keeps-asking-to-authenticate-again-over-and-over/qaq-p/208965)
- [Sourcetree keeps asking for bitbucket password on windows](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-bitbucket-password-on-windows/qaq-p/241278)
- [SourceTree keeps asking for Github password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489022/sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-github-password)
- [Sourcetree keeps asking for login and password](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-login-and-password/qaq-p/146765)

Comment: Months of messing with this and something in this answer finally fixed the problem. Thank you